# Produce the most unique elements with least lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I am new here. I hope I can explain briefly below after giving an example.

```
example1: What is your name?
example1: Where are you from?
example1: How are you doing?
example2: What is your name?
example2: Where are you from?
example2: How are you doing?
example2: When did you move here?
example9: What is your name?
example3: Where are you from?
example23: Who gave you this book?
```

In the above example, I would like to print the unique questions by considering the number of example. So trying something like

expected output

```
 example2: What is your name?
 example2: Where are you from?
 example2: How are you doing?
 example2: When did you move here?
 example23: Who gave you this book?
```

Here, I am searching for the unique questions in a file by considering fewer examples.

I played around something and placing that below.

```
import collections 
s = collections.defaultdict(list)
u_s = set()
with open ('file.txt', 'r') as s1:
    for line in s1:
        data = line.split(':', maxsplit=1)
        start = data[0]
        end = data[-1]
        if end not in u_s:
            u_s.add(end)
            s[start] += [end]
   for start, ends in s.items():
       print(start, ends[0])

       for end in ends[1:]:
           print(start, end)
```

Result that I am getting:

```
   example1  What is your name?
   example1  Where are you from?
   example1  How are you doing?
   example2  When did you move here?
   example23  Who gave you this book?
```

Here, Instead of going to print example1, I want to consider example2 because it is giving more questions.

I tried by sorting the lines based on the repetitions of the line. I couldn't pass through it. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `example2` contains several same questions as those in `example1`, and won't be added to `s[start]`.

Comment: You might explain more about the goal you'd like to achieve. I couldn't get what your expected output is and how the result diverges from that.

Comment: @ChrisTang Thank you. What I am trying is Instead of going to example1 want to go to example2 so that I can get max number of questions. So That What I am thinking is to sort the lines first that are repeating many times and pick the unique once. I Stuck with sorting. In simple words, I would like to print more questions with less examples.

Comment: I suppose what you want is to print the least sets of question examples to produce the most unique questions. Is that right?

Comment: @ChrisTang Exactly

Answer (score 0):

What your code achieved is to print all unique questions but cannot compare or print them in a whole set.

Apart from sorting, I would formulate the problem as to compare the combinations of example sets and select the one that contains the most unique questions with the least sets, so your question is more about the algorithm to me.

```
import collections


def calculate_contrib(values, set):
    '''To calculate the contribution on the unique questions' number, based on values to add.
    values: the list of question set to choose.
    set: the already-added question set.'''
    contrib = 0
    for value in values:
        if value not in set:
            contrib += 1
    return contrib


def print_result(x):
    '''To print the result, x, as a dictionary, without repetition.'''
    u_s = set()
    for key, values in x.items():
        for value in values:
            if value not in u_s:
                print(key,value)
                u_s.add(value)


s = collections.defaultdict(list)
# get all questions in examples
with open('file.txt', 'r') as s1:
    for line in s1:
        data = line.split(':', maxsplit=1)
        start = data[0]
        end = data[-1]
        s[start] += [end]

# Get the initial contribution on the unique questions' number for each example set
contrib = dict()
u_s = set()
result = dict()
for key,values in s.items():
    contrib.update({key: calculate_contrib(s[key], u_s)})

# Execute the while loop when there are unique questions to add to u_s
while not(all([x == 0 for x in contrib.values()])):
    # Add the example set with maximum contribution
    max_contrib = 0
    max_key = ""
    for key, value in contrib.items():
        if max_contrib < value:
            max_key = key
            max_contrib = value
    result.update({max_key: s[max_key]})
    u_s.update(s[max_key])
    del s[max_key]
    del contrib[max_key]
    for key, values in s.items():
        contrib[key] = calculate_contrib(values, u_s)

# print the result
print_result(result)
```

Above is a straightforward implementation, that is adding the example set with the most increase on the unique's number each time until no unique question remains.

Further improvement can be conducted. Hope it could give you some insight.

Comment: Thank you for this. It working perfectly if the questions are repeating. If the question is repeating it is printing twice. I do not want to print it twice.

Comment: @perkinsroyal Minor modification on the code has been made to print the results without repetition. Hope that works for you.